# Iterative Binary Search - String Array

Tags: java, arrays, string, binary-search

I'm trying to create an iterative binary search function as part of a piece of work.

I've tried searching for similar problems but they tend to all be for integer arrays rather than string arrays.

I think the issue with my code is to do with the string comparison operators not executing properly.

If I run the code with some basic test data I get a "java.lang.NullPointerException"

If somebody could take a look at my code and point out where I'm going wrong it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
  public int returnIndex(String searchValue)
  {
    int min = 0;
    int max = data.length -1;
    int mid;

    while (min <= max) {
      mid = min + (max - min) / 2;
      if (data[mid].compareTo(search) == 0) 
      {
        return mid;
      } 
      else if (data[mid].compareTo(search) > 0) 
      {
        min = mid + 1;
      } 
      else 
      {
        max = mid - 1;
      }
    }
    return -1;
  }
```

Edit: I've included my initialisation and test code.

```
public class SortedVector
{
  private int maxlength;
  private int numberofitems;
  private String[] data;
  private int growby;

  public SortedVector()
  {
    maxlength = 10;
    numberofitems = 0;
    data=new String[maxlength];
    growby = 10;
  }
```

In the main.java I call the function and add values to the array:

```
SortedVector Vector = new SortedVector();

Vector.AddItem("Yellow");
Vector.AddItem("Blue");
Vector.AddItem("Green");

System.out.println("The word Yellow is held at index: " + Vector.returnIndex("Yellow"));
```

Comment: Where do you get this exception?

Comment: You should pass the array `data` as parameter to this method.

Comment: Looks to me like your problem is in how your data variable is initialized and you do not provide the code for that. Also it is possible that data[index] may be a null value if not all elements in the array have been initialized to a valid String object.

Comment: I've updated my post to include the initialisation and test code. Hopefully this sheds more light on my issue.

Comment: Note: You can optimize this code by calling `compareTo()` only once and storing the result in a temp variable.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `searchValue` instead of `search`? Two times, when you call `.compareTo`.

Comment: It is search. I think I must have typed searchValue accidentally when copying it over to stackoverflow.

If I debug my code it does execute the while loop, but I think the issue is mid is a number, and I'm trying to compare that to search which is a string. So, for instance, if I typed Vector.returnIndex("B") it's trying to compare 'B' to mid which is 4 for example?

Comment: Not the case. You would get an exception, if you do this. Please pass data as parameter.

Comment: I solved the problem. My else if (data[mid].compareTo(search) < 0)  comparison was the wrong way around. I've changed it from Morethan to lessthan and it's now working perfectly. Thank you for your help Grzegorz! :)

Answer (score 1):

The array `data` has to be sorted before you apply this algorithm.
Besides I strongly recommend passing this `data` array to the method as parameter.

Comment: Oh, okay. At which point do I sort the data? Is it when I'm adding an item to the array?

Comment: You can simply add them as if they were sorted, i.e. `add"A", add("B")`.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks. I've amended my code, but it's still return -1 as the index for any search value. It's almost like my while loop isn't executing.

Comment: Do you pass this `data` array as a parameter? What does `System.out.println(data.length-1)` show in this method?

Comment: It returns 9. I'm not quite sure if I understand your question about how it's passed.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `searchValue` isntead of `search` 2 times in `compareTo` calls?

Answer (score -2):

I think you've added only 3 items to vector but initialized it for 10 items. Then you are trying to get item from mid position.

Comment: Okay, so I tried adding 10 different colours and if I run the code I don't get a null-pointer exception, but it does however think that Yellow is held at index -1.

Comment: @GuestUser140561 this array has to be sorted to use binary search.

Comment: I think there is still problem with initialization. Could you add your code for that?